# Conversion failed when converting varchar value xxxx to int using an enum with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums, nhibernate-mapping

I have an enum property which I want to store and retrieve from the database as a string. NHibernate is able to store the enum as a string but throws the following conversion exception upon retrieval:

> NHibernate.ADOException: could not execute query --> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Pending' to data type int.

Based on the post [Mapping Enumerations with NHibernate](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2006/02/20/138732.aspx) by Jeremy Miller I created the following class:

```
public class WorkflowAction
{
    public virtual ActionStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

which uses this enum:

```
public enum RequestState
{
    Pending,
    Approved,
    Rejected
}
```

which uses this class to transform into a string

```
public class ActionStatusEnumString : NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType
{
    public ActionStatusEnumString()
        : base(typeof(ActionStatus), 50) { }
}
```

and setup the property in my mapping file like this:

```
<property type="Infrastructure.Enum.ActionStatusEnumString, Infrastructure"
    name="Status" column ="status" />
```

As I said this works great for saving data. However, when I want to retrieve via this parameter I receive the conversion exception.

```
return GetSession().CreateQuery(
    @"select distinct requests from WorkflowRequestInformation as requests
    join requests.WorkflowRequestInformationActionList as actions 
    where actions.Status = :status
.SetParameter("status", ActionStatus.Pending)
.List<WorkflowRequestInformation>();
```

NHibernate sends `ActionStatus.Pending` to the database as an integer. My guess is that this is because NHibernate is just running `ActionStatus.Pending.ToString()`.

I can change my code to either of the following and it'll work

```
// defeats the purpose of the enum
.SetParameter("status", "Pending")

// while this feels heavy handed
.SetParameter("status", Enum.GetName(typeof(ActionStatus), ActionStatus.Pending))
```

Is there something built into NHibernate that I am missing that makes this conversion more automatic?

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain to me why you need the 'ActionStatusEnumString' type?
Enums should map as strings by default anyway, so all you need is:

```
<property name="Status" />
```

I do these sort of queries all the time, mapping enums as either strings or ints.

Comment: I added the `ActionStatusEnumString` type because of the error I was receiving and the explanation from this blog post: http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2006/02/20/138732.aspx. I probably should go back and pull it out and see if just using `.SetParameter("status", Enum.GetName(typeof(ActionStatus), ActionStatus.Pending))` fixes my problem. Given the mapping I am guessing that you aren't using fluent, right?

Comment: Actually I do use Fluent NHibernate. If I want an integer instead of a string, I just use Map(x => x.Status).CustomType<WorkflowAction>();

Comment: BTW. The article you link to is from 2006 - a lot of things have changed since then!